# Confusion about norms

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I was doodling at the kitchen table this morning and I seem to have thoroughly confused myself about convex functions and norms.

A norm $||x||$ is a convex function, via the triangle inequality. However, for any convex function $f$, we can show that:
$$
\frac{a}{a+b} f(a+b) + \frac{b}{a+b}f(0) \geq f(a) \\
\frac{b}{a+b} f(a+b) + \frac{a}{a+b}f(0) \geq f(b) \\
\Rightarrow f(a+b) + f(0) \geq f(a) + f(b)
$$

However, using the norm as $f$, gives a violation of the triangle inequality !

I know that I have made a really stupid mistake here - but I just can't figure out what. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how your first equality is supposed to be true... How does the first equality follow from the fact that $f$ is convex?

Comment: $f(a) = f( \frac{a}{a+b} (a+b) + \frac{b}{a+b} 0 ) \leq \frac{a}{a+b} f(a+b) + \frac{b}{a+b} f(0)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $ a $ and $ b $ must be nonnegative scalars, not vectors,  for your calculation to work.

Comment: I think that can be fixed by defining a vector space version of this problem as :   $\bar{a} = a \bar{v}$, $\bar{b} = b \bar{v}$  and $\bar{a+b} = (a+b) \bar{v}$, where $\bar{v}$ is a vector. Also, we can assume $a, b \geq 0$.

Comment: But then the result you get is actually true, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: Ah ! I see it now.

Answer (score 2):

You've shown that for a convex function $f:[0,a+b]\to\Bbb R$ (where $a,b\ge 0$) we must have $f(a+b)+f(0)\ge f(a)+f(b)$. In particular, if $f(x)=|x|$ then equality must hold.  But this simply says that $(a+b)+0= a+b$, and there is no contradiction.